# Построение Master/Slave системы сервисов на базе WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Я понимаю общие принципы Master/Slave, но как это красиво наложить на WCF очень туманно вижу.

Я вижу это абстрактно так:

-Создается 2 сервиса в рамках одной DLL

-В зависимости от конфигурации, сервис будет либо Master, либо Slave

-Как я понимаю, в каждом Slave сервисе должны явно быть прописан адрес Master'a.

-Как я понимаю прокси-клиент нужно ручками описывать, а не генерить автоматически?

-Наверное, Master ничего не должен знать во время запуска о Slave серверах. Slave сервера сами должны заявлять о себе, а Master их должен добавлять.

На сколько мое виденье верное?

Хотелось бы какой банальный пример проекта, который можно было скомпилировать и поиграться.

Comment: Вообще архитектура должна зависеть от требований к вашей системе. Она должна быть отказоустойчивой?Как она будет обновляться? Да и вообще, вы уверены, что вашу задачу нельзя решить просто скриптом на каком нить powershell?

Comment: @tym32167, задачи никакой нет. Просто, спортивный интерес.

Comment: А как должен работать slave? На полную замену? Есть подозрение, что проще делать их равнозначными и балансировщик поставить.

Comment: Тогда я бы использовал либо шину сообщений для слабой связи между сервисами, либо discovery service для обнаружения сервисов, либо все вместе